# Define org mode macro with line breaks

Tags: org-mode

It is possible to [define a macro](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html) in an `org` file as follow:

```
#+MACRO: macroname <here comes the body of the macro>
```

Is it possible to define a macro that contains line breaks? I.e., something like:

```
#+MACRO: macroname line 1 of macro
                   line 2 of macro
```

In particular, this macro will be expanded to

```
line 1 of macro
line 2 of macro
```

My motivation is to have a macro that expands to a block of text which contains, for instance, two paragraphs.

Answer (score 12):

Not only is this possible, it's quite easy to do. You just need to be
creative about how you insert the newline.  I make use of Org Babel to hack the macros. The following works for me:

```
#+MACRO: newline   src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{"\n"}
#+MACRO: macroname line 1 of macro {{{newline}}}line 2 of macro
```

So, given this document:

```
#+MACRO: newline    src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{"\n"}
#+MACRO: macroname line 1 of macro {{{newline}}}line 2 of macro

{{{macroname}}}
```

Exporting to Org mode gives the following

```
# Created 2015-11-03 Tue 15:27
#+TITLE: 
#+AUTHOR:
#+MACRO: newline    src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{"\n"}
#+MACRO: macroname line 1 of macro {{{newline}}}line 2 of macro

line 1 of macro 
line 2 of macro
```

You just have to be aware that some export formats will transform that
newline to a single line when it wraps the text. So, you probably want something like this to get two paragraphs:

```
#+MACRO: newline   src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{"\n"}
#+MACRO: macroname line 1 of macro {{{newline}}} {{{newline}}}line 2 of macro
```

Comment: this is nice, but requires that `{{{newline}}}` be preceded by whitespace. You can hack the newline macro further as `@@html:@@ src_emacs-lisp ...` to ensure there is a space preceding the `src_emacs-lisp` block.

Answer (score 6):

There is another solution which seems to work correctly. From org-macro.el source code:

```
;; VALUE starts with "(eval": it is a s-exp, `eval' it.
        (when (string-match "\\`(eval\\>" value)
          (setq value (eval (read value))))
```

Thus, you may define macro like this:

```
#+MACRO: newline (eval "\n")
```

Substitutions are also supported. The macro

```
#+MACRO: img (eval "#+CAPTION: $1\nfile:$2")
```

which is called as

```
{{{img(hello world!, ./img1.jpg)}}}
```

will be replaced with:

```
#+CAPTION: hello world!
file:./img1.jpg
```

Comment: Note that this does not work anymore, since arguments are now replaced by sexps.  What that means is that $1 will be replaced with "arg" (_including_ quotes).  Your proposition can be changed to `#+MACRO: img (eval (format "#+CAPTION: %1$s\nfile:%2$s" $1 $2))`.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with standard tools at the moment, as
`org-macro--collect-macros` only looks at single line definitions.

Here's a work-around:

```
* Setup                                                                               :noexport:
#+begin_src elisp :exports results :results silent
(setq my-macros
      (mapcar
       (lambda (x)
         (string-match "\\*\\* \\([^\n]+\\)\n\\(.*\\)" x)
         (cons (match-string 1 x)
               (substring x (match-beginning 2))))
       (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline
         (lambda (x)
           (and (= (org-element-property :level x) 2)
                (string=
                 (org-element-property
                  :raw-value
                  (org-element-property :parent x)) "Macros")
                (buffer-substring-no-properties
                 (org-element-property :begin x)
                 (org-element-property :end x)))))
       headings))

(defadvice org-macro--collect-macros (around add-macros activate)
  (let ((r ad-do-it))
    (setq ad-return-value
          (append my-macros r))))
#+end_src
* Macros
** foobar
line 1 of macro

line 2 of macro

** bar
line 1 of macro

line 2 of macro
line 3 of macro
* Test
{{{foobar}}}

{{{bar}}}
```

This approach favors convention over customization, so each macro *has* to be
a level 2 child of level 1 heading with name "Macros".
No additional config necessary: a plain export should work.

The Setup heading should be copied to files where you want this to work.
Or you can add the `defadvice` to your config to have this behavior everywhere.

Comment: This comes closer to what I want/need but it is very cumbersome. I wish there was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is: follow what's suggested by Nicolas Goaziou (i.e., don't use macros for your usage), and find another solution for which you're sure it'll work now and forever.

In this case, I'd either use YASnippets (if just an helper when typing) or Org Babel (if it needs to be customized after having written your document).

Comment: I have `foo.org` and `bar.org`, such that `foo` is included in `bar`. However, I want to be able to define something in `bar` that will add a heading to `foo`. So I think `YAS` is not an option. `Babel` might be..